# How to match an enclosing substring using regex in .NET

Tags: c#, regex, f#

I'm trying to match `*` in `id=resultsStats>*<nobr>` to extract the middle bit.
This would match e.g.
`id=resultsStats>3<nobr>`
`id=resultsStats>anything<nobr>`

so I can extract the middle "3" or "anything"
How do I do this in .NET regex or otherwise?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=id=resultsStats>).+?(?=<nobr>)
```

Use `*` instead of `+` if content is optional rather than required.

Example of use (F#):

```ml
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let tryFindResultsStats input =
    let m = Regex.Match (input,
                         "(?<=id=resultsStats>).+?(?=<nobr>)",
                         RegexOptions.Singleline)
    if m.Success then Some m.Value else None
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regex expert but something like this might work:

```
@"\>\*{1}\<"
```

This means "match a single asterisk between the lt/gt characters". You just need to make sure you escape the asterisk because it has special meaning in regular expressions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: he is not trying to match an actual *

Comment: Also, `>` and `<` do *not* need to be escaped, and `{1}` does nothing but clutter up the regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to capture a `*` then you need to escape it with a backslash. Note that if you are doing this within a string it is safest to escape the backslash as well (Although technically `\*` isn't valid and will work)

```
"\\*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SO6312611
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string input = "id=resultsStats>anything<nobr>";
            Regex r = new Regex("id=resultsStats>(?<data>[^<]*)<nobr>");
            Match m = r.Match(input);
            Console.WriteLine("Matched: >{0}<", m.Groups["data"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why include data you don't care about in the match? Also, he said anything until `<nobr>`, not anything until another arbitrary tag.